# MySQL: Do I need a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table called "PeopleCategory" and it includes
`PeopleCategoryID, Description`

I have two records added

```
1, Customers
2, Partners
```

then I have a table "People" and it includes `PeopleID, PeopleCategoryID, Name`

some records:

```
1, 1, George
2, 1, John
3, 2, Nick
```

The PeopleCategoryID tell us what kind of people is defined.

Do I need a foreign key? I tried this code:

```
ALTER TABLE PeopleCategories
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_test
FOREIGN KEY (PeopleCategoryID) REFERENCES People(PeopleCategoryID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But it fails with error 150.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to add a Foreign Key, it should be in the opposite direction:

```
ALTER TABLE People
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_test
  FOREIGN KEY (PeopleCategoryID) REFERENCES PeopleCategory(PeopleCategoryID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

That way, the people depend on a category and you can't add something to `People` without a corresponding `Category`.

You are probably getting that error because That column is not a primary key in the `People` table.